# Keycloak configured with Azure as IDP and MSAL on Android

Tags: android, azure, keycloak, openid-connect, msal

I'm currently developing an Android application and I'm trying to introduce MSAL with my current Keycloak / Azure authentication flow. However, my backend is set up to validate by Keycloak tokens and I need to maintain this setup.

Here's the flow I'm trying to achieve:

- Authenticate users with Keycloak + Azure AD using MSAL.
- After successful Azure AD authentication, redirect to Keycloak.
- Keycloak redirect to APP.

I'm looking for guidance on how to implement this flow. Specifically, I'm not sure how to configure Keycloak as IDP from MSAL / Authenticator.

If this is not possible, are there any workarounds or alternative approaches to achieve this?

[Sequence diagram of my current flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHdvE.png)

[Sequence diagram of wanted flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh3WB.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to configure MSAL to use Keycloak but couldn't find any way to do that.

I have also looked into B2C which should support other authentication mechanisms but it seemed to be impossible in MSAL for Android, was present in MSAL js.

The authentication flow with keycloak and Azure configured as an identity provider is working perfect, but just need to add MSAL into the picture to achieve SSO. As keycloak will redirect to Azure at login we should be able to reuse the same Azure session if it already has been established by another APP/Browser on the Android mobile phone.

EDIT:
Our current implementation successfully integrates Keycloak and Azure AD for authentication with the system web browser via the AppAuth library. The problem we have encountered arose from a new requirement from one of our customers regarding device Single Sign-On (SSO) functionality.
The customer desires SSO integration with Microsoft apps on their devices, necessitating the implementation of the MSAL Android library in our application to facilitate communication with the Microsoft Authenticator App. However, the MSAL Android library does not use the system browser for authentication when the Microsoft Authenticator App is present on the device. Instead, it defaults to using a WebView.
Given this constraint, authentication via the system browser may not be applicable in our case.

MORE INFO:
The new clients employees use phones with the Microsoft Authenticator App installed. These devices have Shared Device Mode activated(on Authenticator App), enabling Single Sign-On (SSO) and device-wide sign out for Microsoft Teams and other apps that support this mode. The client wants our app to support the same functionality, forcing us to use MS Authenticator App as broker.
My understanding is that while AppAuth is a versatile library, it doesn't inherently support Microsoft-specific features like Shared Device Mode. To utilize Shared Device Mode, it seems that the use of MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) is necessary. More specifically, I believe we need to use the 'MSAL for Android' library for our application. Not sure the 'MSAL for JS' library is applicable to our Android app scenario.

Comment: Personally (- based upon my previous experience), I'd recommend staying away from MSAL and using just OIDC instead; I.M.H.O. MSAL was just adding confusion (& complexity) at the time (- never mind the fact that at the time the documentation was minimal, and then subsequently they rewrote it/changed a lot of it).

Answer (score 0):

I would aim to do it as described below. I do not provide an implementation, which could be quite a bit of work.

**LIBRARY**

Whichever library you use (AppAuth / MSAL), it doesn't need to support particular authentication methods. Its job is to run a code flow on the system browser and hand over to the authorization server (AS).

**AUTHORIZATION SERVER**

Keycloak is your AS and should support any authentication method. You should not need to change any code in your app or switch libraries.

**DIRECT CLIENT INTEGRATION WITH AUTHENTICATION SYSTEMS**

This should usually be avoided since it may limit your authentication options or prevent you getting a correct access token afterwards.

**PLUGIN APPROACH**

The standard OAuth approach would be to use a Keycloak authentication method that interacts with the MS authenticator app. It would perform actions like these:

- Present web forms to the user
- Invoke a deep link to activate the authenticator app
- Poll until the authenticator app has completed

If there is no standard option you might need to implement a custom authenticator using these steps:

- [Use the plugin SDK](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/23.0.6/server_development/#_auth_spi)
- Provide an implementation that adapts code from the [MSAL for Android library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android)

I would start by searching on existing Keycloak authenticators in GitHub repos. You should find that writing a plugin is purely additive and can be done without changing your architecture or adversely affecting your app. Over time you might use multiple plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Our current implementation successfully integrates Keycloak and Azure AD for authentication as you describe. I’m sorry I didn’t communicate this in a good way in the original post. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Ah - good - updated my answer

Comment: "But you could say more about what types of app the customer apps are and how users authenticate / what browsers they use? How will using a TOTP solution like the MS Authenticator App achieve SSO?" Sure I can. I added some more info about this above.